# BlocBuilder calls the function more than once and continuously

Tags: flutter

I'm using state management, specifically the Cubit type.
It was used in the web view because I want to display some data from the web page.
And I made a download icon while loading the webpage..to be comfortable for the user.

I did it with two functions:

- OnPageStarted
- onPageFinished

But these two states are called continuously and repeatedly throughout the life of the application.. which makes the download button appear continuously on the web page, and this makes the page not good.

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_offline/flutter_offline.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import '../Module/InternetConnection/internetconnection.dart';
import '../Shared/Component.dart';
import '../Shared/constant.dart';
import '../Shared/cubit/app_cubit.dart';

class WebViewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const WebViewPage({Key? key, required this.urlPage, required this.titlePage}) : super(key: key);
  final String urlPage;
  final String titlePage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => AppCubit(),
      child: BlocBuilder<AppCubit, AppState>(builder: (context, state) {
        return OfflineBuilder(
          connectivityBuilder: (BuildContext context, ConnectivityResult connectivity, Widget child) {
            final bool connectedWIthNetwork = connectivity != ConnectivityResult.none;
            if (connectedWIthNetwork) {
              return Scaffold(
                appBar: buildAppBar(context, title: titlePage),
                body: SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: double.infinity,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      WebViewWidget(
                          controller: WebViewController()
                            ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
                            ..setNavigationDelegate(
                              NavigationDelegate(onPageFinished: (String url) {
                                debugPrint('\n onPageFinished : Finish Loading\n');
                                debugPrint('\n Before:StatusLoading.finsh\n');
                                AppCubit.get(context).completeLoading(trueFalse: false);
                                debugPrint('\n After:StatusLoading.finsh\n');
                              }, onPageStarted: (String url) {
                                debugPrint('\n onPageStarted : Start Loading\n');
                                debugPrint('\n Before:StatusLoading.Start\n');
                                AppCubit.get(context).completeLoading(trueFalse: true);
                                debugPrint('\n After:StatusLoading.Start\n');
                              }),
                            )
                            ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(urlPage))),
                      AppCubit.get(context).isLoading
                          ? Center(
                              child: Container(
                              width: double.infinity,
                              height: double.infinity,
                              color: Colors.white70.withOpacity(0.1),
                              child: SpinKitFadingCircle(
                                color: blue,
                                size: 100.0,
                              ),
                            ))
                          : const Stack()
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return const NotConnection();
            }
          },
          child: Text(''),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Can any one Help me please?

I only want the two states to be executed once during the loading of the web page, only to bear onpagestarted, and after the completion of the download, to execute OnpageFinished..so that the interface appears correctly and comfortably for the user.

Comment: why are you using `BlocBuilder` on this page? You are not using the `AppState` at all. Trying removing it once.

Comment: I used the Block Builder, to build each page according to the conditions met.. I used the appstete on the two states to change the value from true to false.

Comment: I can see that you are setting the Cubit state using `AppCubit.get(context).completeLoading(trueFalse: false);` But you are not actually listening to the cubit update. So you do not need the BlocBuilder

Comment: Well,, please can you tell me what is the correct solution,, that also solves my problem?

Comment: I guess removing the BlocBuilder will solve it

Comment: Do you know what caused the recurrence?

Comment: The problem was not solved by deleting BlocBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with WebView before, but i would think that creating the "WebViewController" inside of the build method is leading to your callbacks being called all the time.

Create the controller itself in either a State of a StatefulWidget, globally, or inside of your Cubit class.

Edit: here is some working example code as close to your code snippet as possible:

```dart
class AppState {
  final bool isLoading;

  AppState({required this.isLoading});
}

class AppCubit extends Cubit<AppState> {
  late final WebViewController controller;

  AppCubit(String urlPage) : super(AppState(isLoading: true)) {
    controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(onPageFinished: (String url) {
          debugPrint('\n onPageFinished : Finish Loading\n');
          debugPrint('\n Before:StatusLoading.finsh\n');
          completeLoading(trueFalse: false);
          debugPrint('\n After:StatusLoading.finsh\n');
        }, onPageStarted: (String url) {
          debugPrint('\n onPageStarted : Start Loading\n');
          debugPrint('\n Before:StatusLoading.Start\n');
          completeLoading(trueFalse: true);
          debugPrint('\n After:StatusLoading.Start\n');
        }),
      );
    controller.loadRequest(Uri.parse(urlPage));
  }

  void completeLoading({required bool trueFalse}) {
    emit(AppState(isLoading: trueFalse));
  }

  static AppCubit get(BuildContext context, {bool listen = false}) {
    return BlocProvider.of<AppCubit>(context, listen: listen);
  }

  bool get isLoading => state.isLoading;
}

class WebViewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const WebViewPage({Key? key, required this.urlPage, required this.titlePage}) : super(key: key);
  final String urlPage;
  final String titlePage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => AppCubit(urlPage),
      child: BlocBuilder<AppCubit, AppState>(builder: (context, state) {
        return OfflineBuilder(
          connectivityBuilder: (BuildContext context, ConnectivityResult connectivity, Widget child) {
            final bool connectedWIthNetwork = connectivity != ConnectivityResult.none;
            if (connectedWIthNetwork) {
              return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(title: Text(titlePage)),
                body: SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: double.infinity,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      WebViewWidget(controller: AppCubit.get(context).controller),
                      AppCubit.get(context).isLoading
                          ? Center(
                              child: Text("loaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadiiiiiing",
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 40)))
                          : const Stack()
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return const Text("not connected");
            }
          },
          child: Text(''),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}

Widget _build(BuildContext context) {
  return WebViewPage(urlPage: "https://www.google.de/?hl=de", titlePage: "google");
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) => _build(context))),
  ));
}
```

Just remember that if you also want to change your `urlPage` from your code, then depending on your widget structure, you might need to change something, because here the `AppCubit` gets created with the url and navigates to it once, but it would not navigate to a new url if your `WebViewPage` widget is build with a different `urlPage`.

Also for performance reasons its also always best to use the `BlocBuilder` as close to the state access as possible (so inside of the `OfflineBuilder` would be better) and you should directly access the state from the bloc builder to conditionally build children.

The `AppCubit.get(context).isLoading` if the internal `BlocProvider.of` uses `listen=false` is something you should not do if the variable is something depends on the state! In this case it only works because it is inside of the BlocBuilder which already rebuilds the widgets.

Comment: Is everything working now, or do you still need help with something?

Comment: No, nothing worked.. Yes, please, because I did not know what the problem was.

Comment: I editted my answer with an example which is as close as possible to your code snippet. I hope this helps!